# How to model concavity, depression on a mattress surface?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to model a mattress.

How can I model irregular depressions on the surface?

I tried creating on photoshop the pattern, create a normal with shadermap and applying it with a bump but I have several problems, I tried pure modeling but it's too hard for my skills.
I tried boolean, maybe I should try with lattice?[image: you can see irregular depressions]

thank you

Comment: I don't think boolean is a good solution for this type of thing. I'd try the displacement modifier using a height map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really just a starting suggestion; it could be tweaked for ever..

Prepare your mattress for cloth simulation.. I have subdivided this box, triangulated its geometry, and decimated, for this random triangulation. I'm not claiming this is necessarily the best for this. Other topologies may work better.

Create your pattern as flat, reasonably dense, geometry, and [Knife Project](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/knife_project.html) it down onto the mattress. It will remain selected. Make a Vertex group from the projection...

[image]

..and use it as a Pin group in a cloth simulation, including an inflation pressure, which the group will resist.

[image]

I'm sure this could be refined further. Whether or not this is better than, say, masked sculpting, is another question. Maybe someone who knows more about that will contribute an answer.